# Can I publish a POWER BI dashboard using both Direct Query and CSV?

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Power BI Desktop model that uses both a Direct Query source and a CSV.
Can I publish this composite model to PowerBI.com?

My direct query is to the snowflake service.

I am able to publish models that only use Direct Query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that extra configuration may be required in general to publish a Power BI report w/ a CSV source:  [How to publish a report whose data source is CSV](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/How-to-publish-a-report-whose-data-source-is-csv-files-from-a/m-p/752194)